# Using a CAML query how to get a subfolders items based on the URL value the folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, caml

If you right click on a sub folder in a library and select Copy Shortcut.

How do you parse or use the Copy Shortcut value to CAML query the a single folder and its sub folders?

Copy Shortcut value:

```
http://sharepoint.com/siteName/LibraryName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FsiteName%2FLibrary%20Name%2FFolderOne%2FFolder2&FolderCTID=0x01200065B0917E61502A4CB259DB83E8745555&View={D471308F-B032-4973-B7C2-56F75A6C8B46}
```

I'm working with a Visual Studio workflow along with SharePoint 2010.

edit / update

This is what I ended up with:

```
string sCopyFrom = http://sharepoint.com/siteName/LibraryName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FsiteName%2FLibrary%20Name%2FFolderOne%2FFolder2&FolderCTID=0x01200065B0917E61502A4CB259DB83E8745555&View={D471308F-B032-4973-B7C2-56F75A6C8B46}
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(sCopyFrom))
        {
            using (SPWeb webSub = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPList copySource = webSub.GetListFromUrl(sCopyFrom);

                string folderPath = sCopyFrom.Split(new string[] { "RootFolder=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('&')[0].Trim().Replace("%2F", "/").Replace("%20", " ").ToString(); ;

                SPFolder targetFolder = webSub.GetFolder(folderPath);

                // Query to get items
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.RowLimit = 500;                        
                query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
                query.Folder = copySource.ParentWeb.GetFolder(targetFolder.UniqueId);
                query.Query = "";

                do
                {
                    SPListItemCollection collListItems = copySource.GetItems(query);
                    foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
                    {
                        //work with item
                    }

                    query.ListItemCollectionPosition = collListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                } while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use CAML? This can be done without it

Comment: Need to process all the items within a given folder and its children.  Each folder could have a couple thousand docs. Thought using CAML to batch process would be the most efficient route.

Comment: Once you have targetFolder you can get its sub folders by referencing its SubFolders collection.  What is the point of the SPQuery?

Comment: Using SPQuery I was able to get the target folder and the contents of the children folders.  The other part of the workflow works with all the items in a library.  Given the size of the libraries, SPQuery and batch processing is leveraged.  Basically, I needed the ability to process items at the library level or folder level.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't put anything past the 1st part of that in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need CAML.  Try this:

```
    string url = "http://sharepoint.com/siteName/Library Name/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FsiteName%2FLibrary%20Name%2FFolderOne%2FFolder2&FolderCTID=0x01200065B0917E61502A4CB259DB83E8745555&View={D471308F-B032-4973-B7C2-56F75A6C8B46}";
    string siteUrl = new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    string serverRelativeFolderUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url)["RootFolder"];
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(serverRelativeFolderUrl);
            foreach (SPFolder subFolder in folder.SubFolders)
            {
                // do whatever
            }
        }
    }
```

The RootFolder argument on the querystring the server relative URL for the Folder, which is what `SPWeb.GetFolder` takes as its parameter.  You can do whatever you want with the folder object from there, including enumerating its sub folders.

Comment: It was my understanding that you can't use SPContext within a SharePoint workflow.  Is this true?

Comment: That's true...didn't pick up on that in your question when I read it the 1st time.  General approach still works, just need to construct SPSite object from URL.  I updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

In your CAML you'd want to have `<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /></QueryOptions>`

This will look for all files in all folders.

Comment: How do you pass the URL that I provided into the query?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a single folder instead of getting all items, try this:

```
SPFolder oFolderParent = oWeb.Folders[strDocLibName];
//Get Reference to the subfolder
SPFolder oFolderChild = oFolderParent.SubFolders[albumName];
SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)oWeb.Lists[strDocLibName];
SPView oView = oDocumentLibrary.Views["Thumbnails"];
//Get all the photo SPListItems in this subfolder
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.GetItemsInFolder(oView, oFolderChild);
SPListItem item;
for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < collListItems.Count; intIndex++)
{
  item = collListItems[intIndex];
  colImages.Add(item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
}
```